# create dictionary of values based on matching keys in list from nested dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, lookup

i have nested dictionary with upto 300 items from TYPE1 TO TYPE300 called mainlookup

```
mainlookup = {'TYPE1': [{'Song': 'Rock', 'Type': 'Hard', 'Price': '10'}],
```

'TYPE2': [{'Song': 'Jazz', 'Type': 'Slow', 'Price': '5'}], 
   'TYPE37': [{'Song': 'Country', 'Type': 'Fast', 'Price': '7'}]}

input list to search in lookup based on string TYPE1, TYPE2 and so one

```
input_list = ['thissong-fav-user:type1-chan-44-John', 
'thissong-fav-user:type1-chan-45-kelly-md', 
'thissong-fav-user:type2-rock-45-usa',
'thissong-fav-user:type737-chan-45-patrick-md', 
'thissong-fav-user:type37-chan-45-kelly-md']
```

i want to find the string TYPE IN input_list and then create a dictionary  as shown below

```
Output_Desired = {'thissong-fav-user:type1-chan-44-John': [{'Song': 'Rock', 'Type': 'Hard', 
'Price':'10'}],
```

'thissong-fav-user:type1-chan-45-kelly-md': [{'Song': 'Rock', 'Type': 'Hard', 'Price': '10'}],
    'thissong-fav-user:type2-rock-45-usa': [{'Song': 'Jazz', 'Type': 'Slow', 'Price': '5'}], 
    'thissong-fav-user:type37-chan-45-kelly-md': [{'Song': 'Country', 'Type': 'Fast', 'Price': '7'}]}

```
Note-thissong-fav-user:type737-chan-45-patrick-md in the list has no match so i want to create a 
seperate list if value is not found in main lookup

Notfound_list = ['thissong-fav-user:type737-chan-45-patrick-md', and so on..]
```

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
mainlookup = {'TYPE1': [{'Song': 'Rock', 'Type': 'Hard', 'Price': '10'}],
'TYPE2': [{'Song': 'Jazz', 'Type': 'Slow', 'Price': '5'}], 'TYPE37': [{'Song': 'Country', 'Type': 'Fast', 'Price': '7'}]}

input_list = ['thissong-fav-user:type1-chan-44-John', 
'thissong-fav-user:type1-chan-45-kelly-md', 'thissong-fav-user:type737-chan-45-kelly-md']



dct={i:mainlookup[i.split(':')[1].split('-')[0].upper()] for i in input_list if i.split(':')[1].split('-')[0].upper() in mainlookup.keys()}

Notfoundlist=[i for i in input_list if i not in dct.keys() ]
print(dct)
print(Notfoundlist)
```

Output:

```
{'thissong-fav-user:type1-chan-44-John': [{'Song': 'Rock', 'Type': 'Hard', 'Price': '10'}], 'thissong-fav-user:type1-chan-45-kelly-md': [{'Song': 'Rock', 'Type': 'Hard', 'Price': '10'}]}
['thissong-fav-user:type737-chan-45-kelly-md']
```

Answer (score 0):

An answer using regular expressions:

```
import re
from pprint import pprint

input_list = ['thissong-fav-user:type1-chan-44-John', 'thissong-fav-user:type1-chan-45-kelly-md', 'thissong-fav-user:type2-rock-45-usa', 'thissong-fav-user:type737-chan-45-patrick-md', 'thissong-fav-user:type37-chan-45-kelly-md']
mainlookup = {'TYPE2': {'Song': 'Reggaeton', 'Type': 'Hard', 'Price': '30'}, 'TYPE1': {'Song': 'Rock', 'Type': 'Hard', 'Price': '10'}, 'TYPE737': {'Song': 'Jazz', 'Type': 'Hard', 'Price': '99'}, 'TYPE37': {'Song': 'Rock', 'Type': 'Soft', 'Price': '1'}}

pattern = re.compile('type[0-9]+')
matches = [re.search(pattern, x).group(0) for x in input_list]
result = {x: [mainlookup[matches[i].upper()]] for i, x in enumerate(input_list)}
pprint(result)
```

Output:

```
{'thissong-fav-user:type1-chan-44-John': [{'Price': '10',
                                           'Song': 'Rock',
                                           'Type': 'Hard'}],
 'thissong-fav-user:type1-chan-45-kelly-md': [{'Price': '10',
                                               'Song': 'Rock',
                                               'Type': 'Hard'}],
 'thissong-fav-user:type2-rock-45-usa': [{'Price': '30',
                                          'Song': 'Reggaeton',
                                          'Type': 'Hard'}],
 'thissong-fav-user:type37-chan-45-kelly-md': [{'Price': '1',
                                                'Song': 'Rock',
                                                'Type': 'Soft'}],
 'thissong-fav-user:type737-chan-45-patrick-md': [{'Price': '99',
                                                   'Song': 'Jazz',
                                                   'Type': 'Hard'}]}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, this works but when value is not found, it gives key error.